# How to count values of a column that occur within a specific timeframe

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL dilemma that I am trying to solve.
I have two columns: arrivedid and clockin
I am trying to count how many distinct arrivedid occurs within a 30-minute interval before the actual clockin:
For instance:
arrivedid = 4 , clockin = 10:30am

I want to be able to count how many arrived clocked in 1 hour before 10:30am:
so how many arrivedid clocked in 10:00 -10:30 and 9:30-10:00 am

Here is an example of my data:

| arrivedid | clockin |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 2018-07-01T08:30 |
| 102 | 2018-07-01T08:35 |
| 102 | 2018-07-01T08:36 |
| 103 | 2018-07-01T010:30 |
| 110 | 2018-07-01T11:30 |

Comment: Like on a daily basis?

Comment: No, just in a given dataset

Comment: Please post the output you expect based on the given dataset.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important.

Comment: "sql" is not helpful as a tag (nb: if you use "sql-server" please use "sql-server"  tag instead). Each dbms vendor has differences in their SQL implementations - it helps **you** if we propose the syntax that **you** will need. Please use the **"Edit tags"** link at the right of the tags you have already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume SQL Server for the date/time functions and types.

```
-- as two rows
select hour(clockin) as "Hour", count(distinct arrivedid) as ClockIns from T
where cast(clockin as time)
    between cast('09:30am' as time)
        and cast('10:30am' as time)
group by hour(clockin);

-- as one row
select
    count(distinct case when hour(clockin) =  9 then arrivedid end) as "9",
    count(distinct case when hour(clockin) = 10 then arrivedid end) as "10"
from T
where cast(clockin as time)
    between cast('09:30am' as time) and cast('10:30am' as time)
group by hour(clockin);
```

If it's possible for somebody to clock in twice then be aware that it will count them once per time block. So it would double-count those. To avoid that you should de-dup first:

```
with data as (
    select arrivedid, min(clockin) as clockin
    from T
    where cast(clockin as time)
        between cast('09:30am' as time)
            and cast('10:30am' as time)
    group by arrivedid, cast(clockin as date)
)
-- as two rows
select hour(clockin) as "Hour", count(distinct arrivedid) as ClockIns
from data
group by hour(clockin);
```